# Understanding tf/keras source code (for ImageDataGenerator)

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I want to adapt the ImageDataGenerator class in order to let me incorporate my own custom augmentation function. I cannot set my function as the preprocessing_function in the ImageDataGenerators kwargs, since I want to apply this function first before the other standard augmentations.

Looking at the source code for ImageDataGenerator, https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/v2.4.1/tensorflow/python/keras/preprocessing/image.py#L581-L1100 , I don't understand where in the code the standard augmentations are applied to the data.

For example, when I call

```
image_datagen = tf.keras.preprocessing.image.ImageDataGenerator(rotation_range=30)
image_generator = image_datagen.flow_from_directory('./mydir',)
```

Then the images in mydir are having the random rotation function applied to them. But where is this happening in the source code?

Possibly at the end of the source code, https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/85c8b2a817f95a3e979ecd1ed95bff1dc1335cff/tensorflow/python/keras/preprocessing/image.py#L1103 ?

```
keras_export('keras.preprocessing.image.random_rotation')(random_rotation)
```

I don't understand what this line of code is doing?

Comment: Hi @waltwhite ! As you pointed out the last line is doing random rotation in a range 30 degree.